# How to include multiple values in IF statement (Smarty)

Tags: php, templates, if-statement, smarty

We have an IF statement within our smarty templates, which is as follows:

```
{if $category->id == 90}
```

We need to find out how to include multiple categories, so for e.g 95, 96 and 97.

Comment: Arrays, arrays arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just chain them like this:

smarty:

```
{if $category-> == 90 || $category->id == 95 || $category-> == 96}

{/if}
```

You can read more about this topic in the official docs:
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 4):

You can use `in_array()` for that:

```
{if in_array($category->id, [95,96,97])}
```

or

```
{if in_array($category->id, $your_array)}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work unfortunately but the answer by JiiB worked, thank you anyway for your response appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($category->id ) {
    case 90:
        echo "It's 90";
        break;
    case 95:
        echo "It's 95";
        break;
    case 96:
        echo "It's 96";
        break;
}
```

For problems like this switch case is your friend!!! That way you can get every dependency you need and do something else for each situation.

Comment: That is the `switch` syntax plain php.

Comment: I do not think switch in this case will work, looks like he wanna do samething for all the id 90,95,96

Comment: I thought he wants to do something different for each id. I'll just leave this solution here in case it is what OP wants.